# Reading data from a Hyperledger Fabric transaction using Go SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to anchor some data on the Hyperledger Fabric which should be immutable, so that when I read this value anytime in the future, the value should remain the same.

I think I can modify the stateDB and store that data as a key value pair using `stub.PutState`

```
{
  "data": "mydata"
}
```

and note the transaction ID.

However, since the state DB is mutable, I can do something like this instead of doing a `stub.GetState`

```
stub.GetHistoryForKey("data")
```

iterate over and match the transaction ID and then read the value of the key.

However, is there a way to directly read this value from a transaction given that I already have the transaction ID instead of iterating over the history?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use QueryTransaction method to query the ledger for the processed transaction by transaction ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QueryBlockByTxnID` method or `QueryTransaction` method(as mentioned by kartik in the comment). But you need to parse or format the data by yourself.

here's the github reference: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/87f5eb8a655f3d2588e5d1729b2ecf888e52f4ac/pkg/client/ledger/ledger.go#L277